# Unable to call one way Peoplesoft service with WCF-Adapter from BizTalk 2010

Tags: wcf, biztalk, peoplesoft

We are trying to call a one way PeopleSoft service that does not return any response from BizTalk 2010 with WCF-BasicHttp binding and one-way send port.

We are getting the following error.

System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The server did not provide a meaningful reply; this might be caused by a contract mismatch, a premature session shutdown or an internal server error.

I have read several articles regarding this issue. This one says due to reliable delivery feature one way messages are not supported by BizTalk

social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/biztalkgeneral/thread/3a55a044-0a07-416c-9931-1dd6bdeb717a

This one says I need to create WCF proxy that will call a one way web service and return an empty message to BizTalk so the messaging process doesn’t timeout waiting for an answer. (I would like to avoid this if possible)

www.pvle.be/2008/12/calling-one-way-wcf-service-with-biztalk-wcf-adapter-part-2/

At the end of this thread Rajesh says they used SOAP adapter for the same problem. (SOAP Adapter is deprecated)

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/biztalkgeneral/thread/3b58e83a-3b69-40a2-941c-ff2d9a77ccc6

In another thread Rajesh says

As Steef mentioned earlier, a strict one way WCF-Send port is not supported in BizTalk. So you could try changing one-way send port to two-way send port and then you can ignore the response message in your orchestration if you dont need it

I tried changing the one-way send port to two way send port. I'm still getting the same error.

So my question is:

Is it possible to call a service that does not return any response from BizTalk 2010 without writing additional WCF proxies? If yes, can you provide a step-by-step example?

Thanks for your patience with my long post.

Alper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this situation I believe your going to have to write a proxy for it.  BizTalk is all about request / response and one-way is not really one way as people have found out.  Take a look at this article [here](http://seroter.wordpress.com/2010/12/05/error-with-one-way-wsdl-operations-and-biztalk-receive-locations/) as it sheds some light on a similar topic.

Comment: We're exploring the possibility of PeopleSoft service returning an acknowledgement right away (this should satisfy BizTalk) and then start working on the request (retain the async nature of execution)

Comment: Yes, that should work.  BizTalk will need some sort of response even if it's a no content.